# how to change the event order in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I connect my nodejs application to my mongodb through mongoose,

for some purpose, I need to check, if my database contains some data, with some specific title `topic`, I use the `find()` method, to traverse in data one by one and compare it with `topic`, and at the end, if the data not found then need to return some special code say, `not found`.

but despite of checking data in `find()` method, It first shows me the `not found` code,
plz help.

I tried to `console.log()`, to check, which code is executing first

The function is :

```
app.get("/posts/:topic", (req, res) => {
  const topic = _.lowerCase(req.params.topic);
  var found = false;

  posts.find().then((result)=>{
    result.forEach((element)=>{
      if(_.lowerCase(element.postTitle) === topic){
        found = true;
        console.log("checking in posts..");
        res.render("post", {postTitle: element.postTitle, postContent: element.postContent});
      }
    })
  }).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
  

  if(found == false){
      console.log("default");

      // res.render("post", {postTitle: "Oops!...", postContent: "The post you are searching, does not exists.....try again."});
  }

});
```

and it logs the output as :

```
default
checking in posts
```

but it should first check in posts and then go to the end code.....and should log as :

checking in posts
default

Answer (score 0):

I find that you are using Promise in your code but it seems that you don't know what asynchronous in javascript is. You should checkout for [asynchronous](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_asynchronous.asp).
In this code, I suggest you can code like this:

```
app.get("/posts/:topic", (req, res) => {
  const topic = _.lowerCase(req.params.topic);
  var found = false;

  posts.find().then((result)=>{
    result.forEach((element)=>{
      if(_.lowerCase(element.postTitle) === topic){
        found = true;
        console.log("checking in posts..");
        res.render("post", {postTitle: element.postTitle, postContent: element.postContent});
      }
      if(found == false){
        console.log("default");
        // res.render("post", {postTitle: "Oops!...", postContent: "The post you are searching, does not exists.....try again."});
      }
    })
  }).catch((err)=>console.log(err));
  
});
```